# Extbase: findByUid gets wrong object when l10n_parent is used

Tags: php, localization, typo3, extbase

I have a problem with the Typo3 extension I wrote. I shows a product on a page with different designs and functions. For the designs and functions I created m:m relation tables.
The product object is catched with `findByUid()`. Everything works fine in the default language. The product informations, designs and functions are all shown correctly in the frontend. 
But when I choose a localized product object the designs and functions of the default language are shown in the frontend. 
It's a bit complicated to explain. In the backend I create the product object and choose the according localized designs and functions. That works also fine. 
But in the frontend the designs and functions are shown from the default language object but translated. All other information are correct.

The problem only occurs when I choose the `l10n_parent` for the localized product object. When the `l10n_parent` is not set then all functions and designs are correct in the frontend.

I also tried:

```
public function initializeObject() {
    /** @var $querySettings \TYPO3\CMS\Extbase\Persistence\Generic\Typo3QuerySettings */
    $querySettings = $this->objectManager->get('TYPO3\\CMS\\Extbase\\Persistence\\Generic\\Typo3QuerySettings');
    $querySettings->setRespectSysLanguage(FALSE);
    $this->setDefaultQuerySettings($querySettings);
}
```

That didn't change anything.

**EDIT:**
Could it be that this is an unfixed bug:
https://forge.typo3.org/issues/47192
That wouldn't be very good, as I cannot upgrade to LTS 8 due to PHP 7 support. And without `l10n_parent` the backend with my product objects is completely unsorted and very complicated to maintain.

Answer (score 0):

Basically you could use the uid of the record in default language and let extbase do the overlay stuff based on the given language